# Deferring CSS load, why is including preload <link> faster?

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, progressive-enhancement

I'm testing out preloading and I'd like to know *why* including a preload link before a preload script is faster by a tenth of a second.

`rel="preload"` tells the browser to start downloading the stylesheet to not block loading. The script creates a stylesheet from the URL and applies it to the page. Why is the stand-alone-script not as performant?

```
<link rel="preload" href="https://unpkg.com/tachyons@4.8.0/css/tachyons.min.css" as="style" onload="this.rel='tachyons.min.css'">


<script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
  if(document.createStyleSheet) {
    document.createStyleSheet("https://unpkg.com/tachyons@4.8.0/css/tachyons.min.css");
  }
  else {
    var styles = "@import url('https://unpkg.com/tachyons@4.8.0/css/tachyons.min.css');";
    var newSS=document.createElement('link');
    newSS.rel='stylesheet';
    newSS.href='data:text/css,'+escape(styles);
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newSS);
  }
  //]]>
  </script>
```

Preload + Script:
https://codepen.io/JulianNorton/full/GvxpVr/

Script only:
https://codepen.io/JulianNorton/pen/vJRLBK

Comment: You cannot defer css like you can with js. The only way I know of to make css non-render-blocking is **inline any critical CSS** and load the rest in the footer - which is a **maintenance nightmare** in my book.  `rel="preload"` is not supported across all devices and limited to one element at a time to prevent abuse. The best example I can think of to use preload is to preload the entirety of document B at the footer of document A if there's a high chance that the user will end up on document B after they are done with document A

Comment: @Ihazkode one way you can minimize the nightmare is to use toolchains that automatically pre-compile any static HTML files with critical inline CSS, where you can store it in a separate file for development but have it automatically inlined for production. That's a win-win. But according to the MDN page, for browsers that do support `rel="preload"` it doesn't necessarily negate the render-blocking, but it potentially decreases the blocking time by dealing with other preflight mechanisms as quickly as possible.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Curious why you didn't just answer the question. After all, it seems like you know the answer.

Comment: Was responding to the comment, not the question. Link-only answers are not allowed, yet that's all that's necessary to answer the question. Unfortunately, the question is not off-topic, thus, I haven't done anything besides comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found in the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content#The_basics)

```
preload has other advantages too. Using as to specify the type of content to be preloaded allows the browser to:

Prioritize resource loading more accurately.
```

The browser priorities this resource during pre-rendering, marking it as a "stylesheet" required for the critical rendering path, while the  inline element's priority is lower.